# How to free correctly a JSON object with delphi

Tags: json, delphi

I am using Delphi Rio.

I need to create a JSON. My code creates the JSON but I get an AV when I free the JSON Object.

Into my code I have noted the AV occur in js.Free, when I add the  lines:

```
              jaespecs:=GetEspecsFromMedico(fieldbyname('nr').AsInteger);
              jstemp.AddPair('especs',jaespecs);
```

My JSON has this format:

```
{data:[
           {
            data_agenda:'23/02/67',
            medicos:[
             {nome:'pedro',espec:'orto',horai:'',horaf:'',especs:[]},
             {nome:'pedro',espec:'orto',horai:'',horaf:'',especs:[]}
             ]
           },
           {
            data_agenda:'23/02/68',
            medicos:[
             {nome:'pedro',espec:'orto',horai:'',horaf:'',especs:[]},
             {nome:'pedro',espec:'orto',horai:'',horaf:'',especs:[]}
             ]
           }
         ]
}
```

My function works well creating the json except for an AV when I free the JSON with ("js.Free").
Here is the code:

```
function GetJSONPeriodo(datai,dataf: TDatetime;const med:Integer=-1;const espec:Integer=-1): string;
var i:integer;
    dia:string;
    js,jso,jstemp:TJSonObject;
    ja,jatemp,jaespecs:TjsonArray;
    vdata:TDatetime;

    function GetEspecsFromMedico(med:Integer):TjsonArray;
    var qry:TFDQuery;
        je:TJsonObject;
    begin
      je:=TJsonObject.Create;
      result:=TjsonArray.Create;
      qry:=controller.DM.CreateQuery();
      try
          with qry do begin
            close;
            Sql.Clear;
            SQl.Add('select A.nr,B.nome,A.nesp from ESP_QUE_MEDICO_TEM A');
            if prepared then disconnect;
            Open;
            First;
            while not eof  do begin
              je.AddPair('nome',TJsonString.create(fieldbyname('nome').AsString));
              je.AddPair('nesp',TJsonString.create(fieldbyname('nesp').AsString));
              result.AddElement(je);
              next;
            end;
          end;
      finally
        qry.Free;
      end;
    end;

begin
  vdata:=datai;
  js:=TJSonObject.Create;
  ja:=TjsonArray.Create;
  try
      while vdata<=dataf do begin
          i:=DayOfWeek(vdata);
          dia:= uppercase(formatsettings.ShortDayNames[i]);
          with DM.FDQQuery do begin
            Close;
            SQL.Clear;
            SQL.Add('Select B.nr,B.nome,A.hini,A.hfim from HORARIO_ATEND_MEDICO  A');
            if not prepared then prepare;
            parambyname('dia').Value:=dia;
            Open;

            jso:=TJsonObject.Create;
            jso.AddPair('data_agenda',TJSONString.Create(formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy',vdata)));
            jatemp:=TjsonArray.Create;
            while not eof do begin
                  jstemp:=TJsonObject.Create;
                  jstemp.AddPair('text',TJSONString.Create(fieldbyname('nome').AsString));

                  //  if I get rid off the next two lines, no AV occur 
                  jaespecs:=GetEspecsFromMedico(fieldbyname('nr').AsInteger);
                  jstemp.AddPair('especs',jaespecs);

                  jatemp.AddElement(jstemp);
                  next;
            end;
            jso.AddPair('medicos',jatemp);
            ja.AddElement(jso);
          end;
          vdata:=vdata+1;
      end;
      js.AddPair('data',ja);
      result:=js.ToJSON;
  finally
    js.Free;  //I get an AV here
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *GetEspecsFromMedico* you add the same instance *je* to the *result* array multiple times. When the array is freed that instance is freed multiple times, too.

You need to create a new instance of *je* inside the *while not eof* loop.

so. edit your code that.

```
function GetEspecsFromMedico(med: Integer): TjsonArray;
var
  qry: TFDQuery;
  je: TJSONObject;
begin
  result := TjsonArray.Create;
  qry := controller.DM.CreateQuery();
  try
      [...]
      while not eof do
      begin
        je := TJSONObject.Create; // move here
        je.AddPair('nome', TJsonString.Create(fieldbyname('nome').AsString));
        je.AddPair('nesp', TJsonString.Create(fieldbyname('nesp').AsString));
        result.AddElement(je);
        next;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    qry.Free;
  end;
end;
```